# How to change text when scanning barcodes with Zxing via intent in Android?

Tags: java, android, zxing

Is it possible to change the prompt text that says "place the barcode inside the viewfinder..." when launching the Barcode scanner (zxing) via intent ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN")
```

I want to have a prompt in my language, how should I do that?

Comment: As the Zxing is not your application (im guessing), I think you can't do that as you would be altering its code...but if there is a way, i'm interested too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, plain and simple:

```
intent.putExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Your Text Here");
```

Comment: Thanks! btw is there any way to hide Action Bar contents?

Comment: I don't think there is. At least not as of today. Here's the source file which takes the intent extras to parse - I found nothing related to the Action Bar or the Nav Bar.
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java

Answer (score 8):

If it's worth to anyone, here's how you do it with IntentIntegrator if you decided to import ZXings libraries to Android Studio:

```
integrator.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Your message here");
```

Answer (score 2):

Developer here. No sorry you can't do that. But yes if all you mean is you want to contribute a new translation, send us the text.

Comment: I will send you the text(for other menus as well), but i guess it will be a problem because there is still no slovenian locale in android. (at least on my 2.1 htc hero).

Comment: Great, if you are interested in contributing a Slovenian translation (for whenever the locale becomes available) then just translate the strings here: http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/android/res/values/strings.xml

You can send them to me -- I am srowen at gmail. We would of course credit your contribution in the project.

Comment: I will send you my translation within a week.

Answer (score 0):

It reads "Positionieren Sie den Barcode innerhalb des Rechtecks" on my Android. So I guess, the text depends on the handhelds locale setting (as ZXing doesn't provide a setting to change the locale locally).

So if you need support for a now unsuported language, I bet you have to get in contact with ZXings dev team.

Comment: Ok, so this just a thing of locale and there is no way to add some information to intent that would change the text?

Comment: @DixieFlatline - Sorry for the late reply - I think you have to send an email to the zxing dev team. Maybe they have an API to set custom texts on the view.

Comment: PS You can now override the platform Locale within the app itself, starting with the next version of Barcode Scanner (3.8). Barcode Scanner+ has this now (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android)

Answer (score 0):

The proper and modern way to do it is

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntent = new IntentIntegrator(this);
scanIntent.setPrompt("TEXT THAT YOU WANT TO SHOW");
```

Answer (score 0):

With this work perfectly 'cause i'm using it
integrator.setPrompt("Here your text");

and then....when you clicked (mean on result....) you can change the prompt to retry or continue...in this way:

```
builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          // here your new intent or other...like blabla();
    }
}).setNegativeButton("Retry",new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         //even here new itent like  blablabla();
    }
```